# System.Exception: Could not resolve type name

Tags: sitecore

Why would I receive an error like this installation Web Forms for Marketers?

> System.Exception: Could not resolve type name: 
>     Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.AddCustomMetadataProvider, 
>     Sitecore.Forms.Mvc (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode 
>     configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the `Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.dll` in your bin directory. Double check it exists, not then something may have gone wrong with the installation so extract it from the installation package.

If your site is not using MVC then disable `Sitecore.MvcForms.config` form the /App_Config/Include folder.

Comment: thank you for your answer .. the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.dll is present in the bin directory for the published website. We are using MVC. A little history ... I had WFFM up and runnning, but I was having an issue with the form data writing to SQL ... Sitecore claimed that the version of WFFM was not compatible, and thus I loaded a lower version; hence the error.

Comment: Well you're using a a version of a DLL which is not compatible with the rest of the code or that version of Sitecore. An error is to be expected. The latest version of Sitecore (8.1) *does* support writing to SQL database. My recommendation would be to upgrade to this version if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be more specific on what version of Sitecore instance are you using, and also what version of WFFM?

I had an experience with dealing with the installation of WFFM. In some cases it didn't work flawlessly, so what I did was to extract the files from the package and dumped it to the web folders, and it would work (hopefully in your case, as well).

If the workaround didn't work - please do remember that the package contains items as well - So, try to re-validate those items if it were inserted in the database correctly - *this is a pain I know* - but just to be safe, but sometimes to see is to believe. This is the last thing you need to check as the error most likely related to configuration.

**Edited:**  Just a tip. In the *Installation guide* document of the WFFM, there is a **prerequisite** section whereby you can check the version of WFFM against the version of your Sitecore instance. This is just to make sure that you have the correct version of the module. You may find the list of WFFM version [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers.aspx).

Comment: thank you, the funny thing is it was working fine ... i just couldn't get the data to write to the sql table. We overrided the"SaveToDatabase" function using a third party package. I will try what you recommended.